# Is there a single utility allowing to view/modify DACL of all the securable objects in windows?

Tags: windows, security

There are different kinds of securable objects in windows. To name a few:

- files
- registry keys
- certificate keys

More are listed on [Securable Objects on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (although that page misses the certificate keys).

I am wondering if there is a single utility (command line or GUI - never mind) that lets one examine/modify the permissions on each and every kind of securable objects in windows.

I know there is a utility for files (`icacls`).

And then, there is a different utility for registry (`regini`).

And then there are probably other utilities.

For some objects I failed to find any way except coding the respective Win32 API, for instance try changing the permissions of a service certificate keys on windows 2003/XP (for windows 2008/7 one can use [`certutil`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamm/archive/2010/10/26/https-messaging-with-client-side-certificate-fails-with-iis-error-403.aspx)).

So, what about having a single tool (command line or GUI) to work with them all? Is there such a thing out there?

Comment: You would think somebody had already done this, but I couldn't find anything.  If you're up to it you could do it yourself; the Access Control Editor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374865.aspx) is fairly straightforward to implement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the owner of my time.